# Mi función recursiva me elimina los elementos de mi lista

Tags: python, json, recursión

estaria teniendo un problema con una funcion que lo que hace, es almacenar de forma recursiva todas las llaves de un diccionario, que puede ser que ese diccionario tenga a su vez una clave asociada a otro subdiccionarioo anidado, entonces la funcion se llamaria a si misma para corroborar si eso es asi, y en cada llamada que hace, la funcion elimina los elementos que tenia la lista. Alguna ayuda?
El input que le doy es el siguiente:

```
[
{ "name": "George", "id": 12, "email": "george@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 18, "email": "jack@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Joe", "id": 19, "email": "joe@domain.com" }]
```

Otro input:

```
{
"Objects": [
  {
    "ElementName": "Test1",
    "ElementArray": ["abc", "bcd"],
    "ElementUnit": "4"
  },
  {
    "ElementName": "Test2",
    "ElementArray": ["abc", "bcde"],
    "ElementUnit": "8"
  }
]}
```

-> Y la salida de este input deberia ser un vector de llaves con las cuales tendria, [Objects, ElementName,ElementArray,ElementUnit, ElementName,ElementArray,ElementUnit]

Funcion:

```
def check_type(sample_input):
vec_keys = []
print()
if ((type(sample_input)) == dict):
    for key in sample_input:
        vec_keys.append(key)
        print(vec_keys)
elif ((type(sample_input)) == list):
    #Recorremos la lista
    for i in sample_input:
        #Itera cada elemento, si es una lista de objetos, el elemento iterable es el objeto
        print(i)
        check_type(i)
else:
    pass

return vec_keys
```

Comment: Mi objetivo es tener en vec_keys una lista de llaves, siendo las llaves en ese caso, name, id, email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que estabas resolviendo el problema es correcta, solo hay que hacer dos cambios.

Primero, ¿por que se eliminan los elementos de la lista?.

Debido a que estas usando una funcion recursiva la linea `vec_keys = []` se ejecuta en cada llamado a la funcion `check_type()`. Una solucion puede ser usar **inner functions** (una funcion dentro de otra funcion), asi el llamado a generar la lista vacia no se ejecuta en cada recursividad. Mas informacion [aqui](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/)

El segundo punto es que falta agregar la recursividad cuando se cumple esta condicion `if ((type(sample_input)) == dict):` de forma similar al llamado que haces en la linea 13 `check_type(i)`

El codigo quedaria asi:

```py
def check_type(sample_input):
    vec_keys = []
    def get_keys(sample_input):
        if ((type(sample_input)) == dict):
            for key in sample_input.keys():
                get_keys(sample_input[key])
                vec_keys.append(key)
        elif ((type(sample_input)) == list):
            for i in sample_input:
                get_keys(i)
        else:
            pass
    get_keys(sample_input)   
    return vec_keys
```

Asumiendo que se tiene como entrada los valores que propones:

```py
sample = [
{ "name": "George", "id": 12, "email": "george@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 18, "email": "jack@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Joe", "id": 19, "email": "joe@domain.com" }]
```

```py
sample_2 = {
"Objects": [
  {
    "ElementName": "Test1",
    "ElementArray": ["abc", "bcd"],
    "ElementUnit": "4"
  },
  {
    "ElementName": "Test2",
    "ElementArray": ["abc", "bcde"],
    "ElementUnit": "8"
  }
]}
```

Al realizar el llamado a la funcion:

```py
res = check_type(sample)
res2 = check_type(sample_2)
print(res)
print(res2)
```

Se obtiene como resultado en la consola:

```py
['name', 'id', 'email', 'name', 'id', 'email', 'name', 'id', 'email']
['ElementName', 'ElementArray', 'ElementUnit', 'ElementName', 'ElementArray', 'ElementUnit', 'Objects']
```

Nota: Si bien funciona para los ejemplos que presentas, podrian haber casos especificos en los que no se adecue a los tipos de datos y la estructura que tienes como entrada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias la verdad me has resuelto este problema que llevaba bastante dandole, y no sabia como, me pondre a investigar mas acerca de las inner functions, dado que me pueden servir para mi otra parte del problema, que es hacer una lista pero con los valores de las llaves, muchas muchas graciias